# How do pass multiple data types to HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to pass string and int data (possibly other data types like time) to a HashMap to use in a doinbackground task in Android to amend a URL. The URL uses key value pairs to update a mysql database.

I've read about using an object to pass multiple variable types, but can't get it to work.

```
private void addChore(){

    final String title2 = editTextTaskTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    final String description2 = editTextDescription.getText().toString().trim();
    final String person2 = itemPerson.toString().trim();
    final int monday2 = cbMon;

    class NewChore1 {

        String title1;
        String description1;
        String person1;
        int monday1;

        NewChore1(String title1, String description1, String person1, int monday1){

            this.title1 = title1;
            this.description1 = description1;
            this.person1 = person1;
            this.monday1 = monday1;
        }
    }

    class AddChoreM extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(AddChore.this,"Adding...","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(AddChore.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String, NewChore1> params1 = new HashMap<>();

            params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_TASK_TITLE,?);
            params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_DESCRIPTION,?);
            params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_PERSON,?);
            params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_MONDAY,?);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params1);
            return res;
        }
    }

    NewChore1 params = new NewChore1(title2, description2, person2, monday2);
    AddChoreM addChoreM = new AddChoreM();
    addChoreM.execute(params);
}
```

In RequestHandler, I have used the following.

```
private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, Object> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I was not quick enough so there are other answers already but the changes below should work. You can pass your NewChore1 object to your task and extract the parameters in doInBackground:

```
class AddChoreM extends AsyncTask<NewChore1,Void,String> {
```

And:

```
  @Override
      protected String doInBackground(NewChore1...chore) {
              HashMap<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<>();

              params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_TASK_TITLE, chore[0].title1);
              params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_DESCRIPTION, chore[0].description1);
              params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_PERSON,chore[0].person1);
              params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_MONDAY,chore[0].monday1);

              RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
              String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params1);

              return res;
  }
```

Finally:

```
NewChore1 params = new NewChore1(title2, description2, person2, monday2);
new addChoreM.execute(params);
```

**Update:**
Since sendPostRequest only accepts `HashMap<String, String>` you need to change to: `HashMap<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<>();`
And change your NewChore1 class to take only Strings.

Comment: thanks @fluffyBatman for code and Raffe81 for suggesting using <String, Object> which solved 2nd argument type error for putting data pairs into HashMap. I still get a 2nd argument error on the String res (on params1) when using rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params1)

Comment: Could it be that sendPostRequest only accepts HashMap<String, String>. In that case you have to change your int to string. As a quick test you could just do:
HashMap<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<>();
and:
Integer.toString(chore[0].monday1)

Comment: You were right. I have updated that (and code above), and only error I get is "Expression expected" on returning res in doInBackground... am having posting same messages on @fluffyBatman, so will keep comments going there to avoid double ups J

Comment: I dont know which code you are using. But if you are using the fluffyBatmans code with the "if(newChore1Obj != null) {" expression. Then res is only created inside the if. Try putting "String res" before the if. Then inside just res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params1);

Also since the above worked you should not use the " Integer.toString", that was just for testing purpose. Instead change your NewChore1 class to take all Strings

Comment: Yip, that did the trick. Thanks! Been working on this for a while J

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor for `AddChoreM` class and set your `NewChore1` object through it. You can now easily extract the properties of `NewChore1` in `doInBackground`.

```
class AddChoreM extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

  ProgressDialog loading;
  NewChore1 newChore1Obj;

  public AddChoreM(NewChore1 newChore1Obj){
          this.newChore1Obj = newChore1Obj;
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void...v) {
          HashMap<String, NewChore1> params1 = new HashMap<>();
          String res = "";
          if(newChore1Obj != null) {
                  params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_TASK_TITLE, newChore1Obj.title1);
                  params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_DESCRIPTION, newChore1Obj.description1);
                  params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_PERSON,newChore1Obj.person1);
                  params1.put(Config.KEY_CHORE_MONDAY,newChore1Obj.monday1);

                  RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                  res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params1);
          }
          return res;
  }

  // Other methods of AsyncTask
  //
}
```

Finally, create and execute `AddChoreM` like this.

```
NewChore1 params = new NewChore1(title2, description2, person2, monday2);
AddChoreM addChoreM = new AddChoreM(params);
addChoreM.execute();
```

Comment: I get "Wrong second argument type.Found String, required newChore1 .. for each item passing to params1

Comment: From the look of it, I think you want `HashMap<String, NewChore1> params1 = new HashMap<>();` to be `HashMap<String, Object> params1 = new HashMap<>();`. Can you check that again?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I changed NewChore1 to use Object and that solved the issue for putting the items into the HashMap, but I still get the error on params1 when using rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params1), and also on res being returned, which I guess makes sense

Comment: UPDATE: I changed the HashMap data type in RequestHandler to Object also which has sorted the data incompatible error on params1. The only error I get now is on return res; saying Expression expected

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
Map<String, Object> params1 = new HashMap<>();
```

then you can store any type as value within the map.